# performance testing of an application using dummynet

Tags: android, networking, emulation

I have installed network emulator, dummy-net in window 7 and tried some ipfw commands for limiting bandwidth, latency and queue size, etc.

```
ipfw pipe 1 config bw 1MByte/s delay 100ms queue 10
ipfw add pipe 1 ip from any to any
```

But I have following problems:

1. How can I judge the effect of changing bandwidth, latency ,queue
   size, etc, quantitatively?
2. I have to check the performance of  mobile phone application using
   this emulator. How can I check?

Please suggest me anything related to this.